# Implement a single iteration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, iteration

So I came into this online test question, something like this :

> Write a function to check if the given value is a single digit. If it is not, add up all the numbers until it becomes a single digit. For example, the given value is 55555 resulting 25. When 2 and 5 added will get 7.

And here is my answer :

```
function createCheckDigit(membershipId) {
  let sum = 0;
  let array = membershipId.toString().split("")
  if(array.length > 1){
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      sum = sum + parseInt(array[i]);
    }
  }
  if(sum.toString().split("").length > 1){
    return createCheckDigit(sum.toString())
  } else {
    return sum
  }
}

console.log(createCheckDigit("55555"));
```

The goal for this question is:

1. test case answer = 7 **(done)**
2. single iteration required **(required)**
3. two iterations required **(done)**
4. multiple iterations required **(done)**

I managed to get 1, 3, 4 fulfilled but not 2. I don't understand which part should the single iteration takes place?

Comment: I think that means for a value like `12` you know the result (3) after just one call to the function, and no further recursion is necessary.

Comment: What are the values being passed in 2. ?

Comment: Won't change anything, but because of type coercion (triggered by the `>` operator) `if(sum.toString().split("").length > 1)` can be `if(sum > 10)`

Comment: @Pointy you're genius! That's exactly what it means. Just added else condition for the first array length checking by returning membershipId and it's completed. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found a solution to the problem:

```js
function checkDigit(v) {
    let sum = 0;
    const digits = v.toString().split("");
    for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; ++i) {
        sum += Number(digits[i]);
        if (sum >= 10) {
            sum -= 9; // same as (sum - 10) + 1; this works because we won't ever get a sum greater than 9+9=18 so the sum of those digits will be a single digit
        }
    }
    
    return sum;
}

console.log(checkDigit('55555'));
console.log(checkDigit('2'));
console.log(checkDigit('12345'));
console.log(checkDigit('99999'));
console.log(checkDigit('775542'));
```